# Three way binding from a ul list in angularfire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to sync data to firebase.

This works using the 3 way binding.

```
var ref = new Firebase('xxxxxxxxx');

$scope.mydata = $firebaseObject(ref);

<input type="text" id="myid" ng-model="mydata.foo" ng-change="mydata.$save()" placeholder="insert here...">
```

I am trying to get this to work below, but I am struggling.

```
var ref = new Firebase('xxxxxxxxx');

$scope.mydata = $firebaseObject(ref);

<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  <li><a href="#" ng-click="mydata.$save()" ng-model="mydata.foo">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" ng-click="mydata.$save()" ng-model="mydata.foo">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" ng-click="mydata.$save()" ng-model="mydata.foo">Something else here</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `$event` into the function to get the target element, therefore getting the `innerText`. This however, would be best served as a directive since it's not kosher to interact with the DOM in your controller.

**[Plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hLgKFw4snvgwuByA7rPi?p=preview)**

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

function MyController($scope, rootRef, $firebaseObject) {
  $scope.mydata = $firebaseObject(rootRef.child('data'));
  $scope.updateText = function updateText($event) {
    $scope.mydata.foo = $event.target.innerText;
    $scope.mydata.$save();
  };
}
```

Then in template, just pass in the `$event`.

```
  <input type="text" id="myid" ng-model="mydata.foo"  placeholder="insert here...">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="updateText($event)">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="updateText($event)">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="updateText($event)">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
```

But as I mentioned before, you would be best served creating a directive out of the `<a>` tag. That handles getting the innerText for the ng-click underneath the hood.

```
<update-link ng-model="mydata.foo">Update</update-link>
```

But demonstrating how to make that is for another question :)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the quick response, could you take another look at your plunk please, it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: It works for me. What are you expecting to see? Or are there any errors?

Comment: Hi David, I was expecting to click on one of the li's and the text value will be saved to the firebase ie: click on "action" and "action" will be attached to "foo", click on "Another action" and that updates "foo" and so on...

Comment: That's what I see it do. Open up the Firebase url in a browser and see it update when you click. Or even just refresh the page after a click.

Comment: Ah, I see what you have done, the value from the input is updating the firebase when the li's are clicked. What I really want to do is not have the input involved at all (I was using that as an example of what I can do) and update the firebase with the text value in the li. eg: click on "action" and pass the word/value "action into the firebase. BTW: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Oooooooo give me a second I can do that

Comment: Updated to save the `a`'s text value.

Comment: Great David! Perfect. Thanks a million